# Is there a heat resistant perennial vine that can grow in my zone?

Tags: grass, vines

I live in Montana, here is my zone information:

- 1990 Hardiness Zone: Zone 4b: -25F to -20F
- Average First Frost: September 1 - 10
- Average Last Frost:  June 1 - 10
- Koppen-Geiger Climate Zone:  Dfb - Humid Continental Mild Summer, Wet
  All Year
- Ecoregion:   17g - Mid-elevation Sedimentary Mountains
- Elevation: 4793'

On the south side (sun facing side) of my house the light, and heat seems to be reflecting off the house, and onto the grass below starving it of the moisture it needs to survive. I have been struggling to keep grass growing there. At the moment (mild summer) I have managed to keep it alive for the most part with new grass seed, and a small shader I built out of window screen. I would like to put trellis all along that side of the house to grow a vine to provide the grass in that region shade. Does anyone know of a heat resistant perennial vine that will do the job I am looking for, and thrive in my region of the world?

Comment: Having grown wonderful vines from seed that turned out to be invasive it's always a safer bet to grow what grows in your area.  Looking at you: porcelain berry vine, clematis tangutica, Russian Mile a minute vine

Comment: Porcelainberry is also invasive.

Comment: Can I ask what your summer temperatures are? Looking up USDA zone 4b only tells me how cold it gets... (pretty cold, with long winters, meaning a very cold hardy vine is necessary)

Comment: @Bamboo The average summer temp is 85.

Comment: Or a clematis, though that will need mesh over a trellis to cling onto https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/garden-how-to/gardening-by-zone/zone-4/clematis-varieties-for-zone-4.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly a Honeysuckle vine: https://www.gardendesign.com/vines/honeysuckle.html
I've had good luck with mine in an environment not too dissimilar from yours.
Added advantage, the vine stays small enough not to try to rip apart my garage.